# doctrine:build-schema ignoring unique key

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

i am using the symfony command to generate my schema.yml file from my mysql 5.1 database by running:

```
symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `identity` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Gets converted into:

```
Identity:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: identity
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    username:
      type: string(64)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(128)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
```

It all looks fine, except i'm expecting the username column to look like (e.g. with the `unique: true`):

```
    username:
      type: string(64)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
      unique: true
```

Does anyone know what i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `identity` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `identity_username_idx` (`username`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming the key something other than `(column)` or `(column)_idx`; e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `identity` (
  ...

  UNIQUE KEY `username_unique` (`username`)
) ...
```

I can't find this documented anywhere, but I noticed while creating a Doctrine behavior that if I try to create an index whose name matches a column, Doctrine will rename it to `(column)_idx` and refuse to make it unique.